# How to use mexCallMATLAB from c++ with matlab function which gets function handle?

Tags: c++, matlab, mathematical-optimization, mex

I want to run `lsqnonlin` which is a matlab optimization function from C++.
From matlab it is called as follows:

```
  lsqnonlin(@(x)funcHandle(x,var1,var2,..),x_initial,[],[],options);
```

From metlab c++ API I understoodt that `mexCallMATLAB` is the function I should use to call matlab and get the output

```
  int mexCallMATLAB(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs,mxArray *prhs[],
  const char *functionName);
```

how do I pass all the arguments to mexCallMATLAB - {funcHandle,var1,var2,..,x_initial,[],[],options}, especially the function handle? I found this "mclCreateSimpleFunctionHandle" function, but I'm not sure how to use it? I have a mexFunction implementation of the funcHandle, and created a mexw64 version of it, I think I should use that somehow..

Thanks

Comment: Did you read the documentation in [mexCallMATLAB](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/apiref/mexcallmatlab.html), specifically the examples. You provide the input arguments to function in `prhs` (pointer to Right-Hand-Side arguments) and collect the result in `plhs` (pointer to Left-Hand-Side arguments)..

Comment: Thanks, sure I did. But how do you pass a funcHandle as a mexArray to prhs? How should this function be defined? Should it be compiled, how? How do I get the handle to it's compiled version? Where should this compiled version be, so matlab will find it? Is my order of variables passed is the order to insert to prhs? is function name is only "lsqnonlin"?

Comment: Possible answer here: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/96775-how-do-i-pass-function-handles-to-c-mex-function-in-matlab-7-8-r2009a

Comment: thanks, it's related. But I'm running a c application which calls matlab and not the other way around. The matlab function that I need is lsqnonlin..

Comment: There is a link to a cpp-file http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/uploaded_files/1750/simplefunction.cpp which parses a function handle as argument

Comment: Yes I know, so you say that in order to get a function handle from matlab to another matlab func, I should write a mex function wrapper that gets the function handle from matlab. The thing is that I run a cpp project, so I'm not in matlab, and don't want to run my project from matlab. I need to get this function handle by calling some cpp API function from my visual studio and pass it to mexCallMATLAB as a mexArray..

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood what you wanted. Sounds difficult according to https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/274319